# How to open files with an incremental numbers?

Tags: python

Right now I'm doing this:

```
filenames = ['ch01.md', 'ch02.md', 'ch03.md', 'ch04.md', 'ch05.md', 'ch06.md']
with open('chall.txt', 'w') as outfile:
   for fname in filenames:
```

But I have many files written as chxx.md (until `ch24.md`). Is there any what to modify the script using ranges? So I don't have to type in all the files names?

Comment: replace first line by `filenames = glob.glob('ch*.md')`

Comment: @itzmeontv It works but weird. The concatenation stops on `ch14.md` and I have files until `ch24.md`

Comment: to sort  == > `sorted(glob.glob('ch*.md'))`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can probably use `glob`. It's an easy way to collect files with the use of wildcard characters.

```
import glob
filenames = glob.glob('/yourDirectory/ch*.md') # Will give you a list of all the file names
with open('chall.txt', 'w') as outfile:
   for fname in filenames:
```

Comment: Weird. I have until `ch24.md` and the files concatenate but they stop on `ch14.md`.

Comment: They're all from the same directory? There's nothing that differentiates them from the ones that work? `glob` should picked those up.

Comment: Oh, what happened is, they were concadenated in wrong order: `['ch03.md', 'ch16.md', 'ch09.md', 'ch20.md', 'ch24.md', 'ch11.md', 'ch23.md', 'ch22.md', 'ch02.md', 'ch12.md', 'chall.md', 'ch19.md', 'ch06.md', 'ch18.md', 'ch05.md', 'ch13.md', 'ch08.md', 'ch15.md', 'ch10.md', 'ch07.md', 'ch21.md', 'ch01.md', 'ch17.md', 'ch04.md', 'ch14.md']` How can I make them concatenate in order?

Comment: Ah, you can wrap `sorted(filenames)` to get them in the right order.

Comment: @itzmeontv Thanks a lot. I'm a Python beginner. One question, why do I need this `key=lambda x:x[2:]`?

Comment: No need of `key=` here,since string length are all same.I did it so because to sort based on string from `3rd` character.That means from  `14` in `ch14.md`.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use `for x in` syntax, as follows:

```
filenames = ['ch0'+str(x)+'.md' for x in range(7)]
```

Comment: Oh, I like this. But some files read like `ch12.md.`. How to deal with them?

Comment: @alexchenco in that case, you can use `.zfill()`:  `filenames = ['ch'+str(x).zfill(2)+'.md' for x in range(7)]`

Answer (score 0):

Just do :

```
with open('chall.txt', 'w') as outfile:
    for index in range(1, 7):
        filename = 'ch' + index.zfill(2)  + '.md'
```

Answer (score 0):

[python 2 string formating](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#string-formatting-operations)

```
filename = 'ch%02d.md' % file_index
```

[python 3 string formating](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

```
filename = 'ch{0:02}.md'.format(file_index)
```

Answer (score 0):

My attempt with `o.walk` and `re` pattern is customizable.Better is you have nested directory, in this case just get the path of mother folder as `seacrh_folder`.

**In this approach you have more control over the file name then any other methods.**

```
import os,re
pattern = re.compile(r'ch[0-9]+(?=.md)')

seacrh_folder = r"C:\Users\USER_NAME\Desktop"

for root,dir,files in os.walk(seacrh_folder):
    for file in files:
        if pattern.match(file):
            print file
            #do something
        else:
            pass
```

Prints-

```
ch01.md
ch012983928338.md
ch0344.md
```